# Jasmine - Only "it" Blocks Running

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a few test cases in this sort of format.

```
describe("", () => {
    console.log("describe1");
    beforeEach(() => {
        console.log("beforeEach");
    });

    describe("", () => {
        console.log("describe2");
        it("", () => {
            console.log("it1");
        })

        it("", () => {
            console.log("it2");
        })
    });
});
```

The problem I'm having is that I get every single test running perfectly but then when all the tests have ran it runs every test again but without running the beforeEach blocks which is making my tests fail.

So the above code would print as such...

```
describe1
describe2(note that the "it"s are not executed)
beforeEach
it1
beforeEach
it2(so far so good but now...)
it1(notice how before each didn't run but the "it"s were reran here and below)
it2
```

**So what I'm not understanding is why it1 and it2 run again without the before each.**

**Note:**  I am running this code using **Karma Test Runner**

Comment: This doesn't make so much sense on its own. Do you have a full reproducible example?

Comment: @SkinnyJ This is code from work so I'm not sure if I'm allowed to post it, but basically I just don't understand why my "it"s are getting executing a second time once they have already done their job.  Could it have anything to do with the Karma config file.

Comment: Neither do I and yes

Comment: @SkinnyJ In that case I tried using patters in teh Karma Config file instead of just writing out the directory location of the file but then I get undefined elements in Jasmine's jasmine-html file

Comment: AFAIK `describe` and `it` have a String as first argument and a function as **second**.

Comment: @MarcoL that's just an example of the format.  I have real tests I just didn't think I needed to write them down.  The point is that my it blocks get executed a second time without the beforeEach blocks

Comment: Reading your code again, the "beforeEach" should be printed only once in your output, before "describe2", not for each nested "it" block.

Comment: @MarcoL  I'm pretty sure the problem was that I was using an older version of Jasmine but I was still including jasmine/boot.js which wasn't compatible with older versions of Jasmine